# How to add more than one behavior to a table in cakephp 3.X

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have two behaviors I will like to implement in a table. One behavior deals with uploading image while the other deals with encrypting id. My problem however is only the first behavior works anytime I want to implement the behaviors. Below is my table

```
public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->table('image_reports');
        $this->displayField('id');
        $this->primaryKey('id');
        $this->addBehavior('Utils.Uploadable', [
            'image'=>[
                'path'=>'{ROOT}{DS}{WEBROOT}{DS}img{DS}image_reports{DS}',
                'field' => 'id',
                'fileName' => '{field}.{extension}',
                'fields'=>[
                    'fileName'=>'image_name'
                ]
            ],
        ]);
      $this->addBehavior('Hashable');
}
```

Only the first behavior called works, when i called 'hashable' first, that worked but uploadable didnt, when uploadable was called first, it worked but hasable didnt.
I need help as there is nothing in the docs as per this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I got help from my mentor, both behavior makes use of afterSave callback event, so I had to change one to make use of save callback.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try...

See which behaviors are loaded

```
$table->behaviors()->loaded();
```

Check if a specific behavior is loaded.
Remember to omit plugin prefixes.

```
$table->behaviors()->has('CounterCache');
```

Get a loaded behavior
Remember to omit plugin prefixes

```
$table->behaviors()->get('CounterCache');
```